# AWS kubernetes pricing clarification

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have setup a 5 node kubernetes cluster in AWS using KOPS. I have installed an application on the same. I use the application only for 7 to 8 hours a day and few days in a month. Is there any provision in KOPS wherin I scale down the nodes to zero when there is no traffic and scale up the nodes when I want to use the application.

I would also like to know will I be billed in AWS if I scale the nodes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [cluster-autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler).
The tool will control the EC2 autoscaling group in order to add cluster nodes when pods cannot be scheduled, and remove cluster nodes when they are underutilized.